# how to remove SOQL from For Loop

Tags: apex, trigger

Can someone plz help me to remove the SOQL query from inside the For loop. I have already removed some SOQL query from inside for but I am having difficulty in removing the SOQL from outer for loop..

```
public static void setSellerName(List<Acquisition__c> acqs, Map<Id, Acquisition__c> oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap) {    
        String oldDeal= null;
        Map<String, Id> dealToFirmId = new Map<String, Id>();
        Map<Id, String> firmMap = new Map<Id, String>();
        
        **for (Acquisition__c acq : acqs)** {
            if (acq.Deal__c != null) {
                dealToFirmId.put(acq.Deal__c, null);
            }
            if (dealToFirmId.size() > 0) {
                for (Opportunity deal : [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE id IN :dealToFirmId.keySet()]) {
                    dealToFirmId.put(deal.Id, deal.AccountId);
                    firmMap.put(dealToFirmId.get(acq.Deal__c),null);
                } 
            }
            
            for (Account accounts :[Select Id, Name from Account WHERE id IN :firmMap.keySet()]){
                firmMap.put(accounts.Id, accounts.Name);
            }
        }
        List<Account> accName = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :firmMap.keySet()];
        for (Acquisition__c acq : acqs) {
            if (oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap!= null)
                oldDeal = oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap.get(acq.id).Deal__c;

            if (acq.Deal__c != oldDeal)
                acq.Seller_Name__c = accName[0].Name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this code does is setting `acq.Seller_Name__c` as the name of the Opportunity's Account if the opportunity has changed.

You don't need a query on Account, since you can get that name from the query on Opportunity and store it in a map that relates the opportunity id to the account name.

A first loop over Acquisition__c, to put the opportunity id into the map as key, is mandatory. By the way, there is no need of an `if (acq.Deal__c != null)` since you can remove the null key after the loop.
Then, if the map is not empty, you could query the opportunities to get the account name and store it into the map.
Now you can loop again over Acquisition__c, check whether the opportunity has changed and if so set the right Seller Name.

These advices result in the following code:

```java
public static void setSellerName(List<Acquisition__c> acqs, Map<Id, Acquisition__c> oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap) {    
    // if oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap is null you're never going to set Seller_Name__c
    // so you should exit as soon as possibile
    if (oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap == null) {
        return;
    }

    Map<Id, String> opportunityIdToAccountName = new Map<Id, String>();
    for (Acquisition__c acq : acqs) {
        opportunityIdToAccountName.put(acq.Deal__c, null);
    }
    opportunityIdToAccountName.remove(null);

    if (!opportunityIdToAccountName.isEmpty()) {
        for (Opportunity deal : [SELECT Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opportunityIdToAccountName.keySet()]) {
            opportunityIdToAccountName.put(deal.Id, deal.Account.Name);
        }

        for (Acquisition__c acq : acqs) {
            Id oldDeal = oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap.get(acq.Id).Deal__c;
    
            if (acq.Deal__c != null && acq.Deal__c != oldDeal) {
                acq.Seller_Name__c = opportunityIdToAccountName.get(acq.Deal__c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When doing an insert operation, you want to set the seller name regardless, if a deal is set on the acquisition.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the SOQL query from the outer for loop, you can use a map to store the result of the SOQL query and then use the map to set the values for the Seller_Name__c field. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
 public static void setSellerName(List<Acquisition__c> acqs, Map<Id, Acquisition__c> oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap) {    
    String oldDeal= null;
    Map<String, Id> dealToFirmId = new Map<String, Id>();
    Map<Id, String> firmMap = new Map<Id, String>();

    for (Acquisition__c acq : acqs) {
        if (acq.Deal__c != null) {
            dealToFirmId.put(acq.Deal__c, null);
        }
    }

    if (dealToFirmId.size() > 0) {
        for (Opportunity deal : [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE id IN :dealToFirmId.keySet()]) {
            dealToFirmId.put(deal.Id, deal.AccountId);
            firmMap.put(dealToFirmId.get(acq.Deal__c),null);
        } 
    }
    
    for (Account accounts :[Select Id, Name from Account WHERE id IN :firmMap.keySet()]){
        firmMap.put(accounts.Id, accounts.Name);
    }

    for (Acquisition__c acq : acqs) {
        if (oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap!= null)
            oldDeal = oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap.get(acq.id).Deal__c;

        if (acq.Deal__c != oldDeal)
            acq.Seller_Name__c = firmMap.get(dealToFirmId.get(acq.Deal__c));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all... have you considered using a formula? Formulas are automatically updated when you query them, which would be a no-code solution.

The formula field would look something like this:

```
Seller Name (Text) =
Deal__r.Account.Name
```

Alternatively, you can reduce the complexity of your code significantly by querying the accounts from the opportunities, which you can further optimize by keeping track of which records were modified:

```
public static void setSellerName(List<Acquisition__c> acqs, Map<Id, Acquisition__c> oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap) {    
    Map<Id, Opportunity> deals = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    Acquisition__c[] updatedAcquisitions = new Acquisition__c[0];
    // Aggregate the values to query
    for (Acquisition__c acq : acqs) {
        if(acq.Deal__c != null && acq.Deal__c != oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap?.get(acq.Id).Deal__c){
            deals.put(acq.Deal__c, null);
            updatedAcquisitions.add(acq);
        }
    }
    // No work to do here
    if(deal.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    // Get the results into a map
    deals.putAll([
        SELECT Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :deals.keySet()
    ]);
    // And update the acquisition records
    for (Acquisition__c acq : updatedAcquisitions) {
        acq.Seller_Name__c = deals.get(acq.Deal__c).Account.Name;
    }
}
```

Note the use of [`?.`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm), which handles the situation when `oldTriggeredAcquisitionsMap` is null (when handling a before insert DML trigger).